# Remote MySQL connection not working

Tags: mysql, remote-connection

I'm trying to access my website's MySQL database I have remotely. I've followed instructions to set up MySQL Workbench's parameters and I have the Username, Password and all those. My problem is, after I've allowed my IP to access it, when I try to connect it says

> Failed to Connect to MySQL at 173.254.28.62:3306 with user **********  Can't connect to MySQL server on '173.254.28.61'(10060)

The IP 173.254.28.61 I got from pinging my website's adress (http://www.motivateddreams.com/) with CMD. When I try to navigate to that IP in my browser, It says "There is no website configured at this address." The thing it though, I know it exists. I type ping motivateddreams.com into CMD and that's what it gives me. Any ideas? Is there a way to get the correct IP address of a website? Or is it a different problem?
P.S. If you need more info, please ask and don't just vote this question down.

**EDIT**

Thanks everyone for your help :D I got it working with some help from the host, but I'll choose a best answer anyway.

Comment: Why don't you check with your host? The IP you're likely getting is not associated with your `MySQL` instance.

Comment: In the instructions, I was supposed to use "the server ip" for the host

Comment: https://my.justhost.com/cgi/help/89

Comment: Did you follow the instructions, where it asks *"Allowing a Remote Server to Access Your Database"*.

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure what IP I was supposed to use so I used they're provided IP: `Note: You can find and add your IP address directly from this tool. Look for Your IP is: 123.123.12.123 [Add]. Clicking the [Add] link will input your IP into the field box below.`

Comment: Is your MySQL instance configured to allow the remote connection to the database?  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-windows-excerpt/5.1/en/mysql-config-wizard-networking.html

Comment: Generally the external IP access to the Production Database is restricted due to security concerns.  Connecting to the database with local IP using VPN connection would be ideal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pinging motivateddreams.com [173.254.28.61] with 32 bytes of data:

Reply from 173.254.28.61: bytes=32 time=187ms TTL=50

Reply from 173.254.28.61: bytes=32 time=178ms TTL=50

Reply from 173.254.28.61: bytes=32 time=182ms TTL=50

:D

But asides that I'm guessing a firewall issue here. Is there an option to allow a specific host in your workbench/cpanel/whatever site?

I remember one of my webhosters that I could allow a remote host for mysql.

And I think that you have granted the rights to the 'user'@'yourhost' right?

Comment: 173.254.28.61:  There is no website configured at this address. That's what happens when I try to navigate to it

Comment: Well that's just the IP I get from Switzerland when pinging your site. You'll see the same message with .62 -> You'll have to update your IP with their database as @FreshPrinceOfSO suggested "Allowing a Remote Server to Access Your Database"

Comment: It's the same one I got too

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken, the ping test for determining the IP of a website is not 100% fire-proof. There might be other computers by that name, so that the IP return from the PING is simply the first one on the list, which is probably not the one corresponding to the website you want. At least, that´s why I was taught when the same problem ocurred.

I just used this [site](http://www.selfseo.com/find_ip_address_of_a_website.php) to find the IP address and I got this: 173.254.28.61

Maybe the problem is the IP address and not your setup.

goodluck!